# Linux Kernel - Beagle Bone - PWM Pin Muxing - Device Tree

Tags: linux-kernel, beagleboneblack, device-tree, pwm

I'm trying to mux gpmc_ad9 pin in PWM mode through the device tree

file: arch/arm/boot/dts/am335x-boneblack.dts

```
&am33xx_pinmux {
    hw_pins: hw_pins {
        pinctrl-single,pins = <
             AM33XX_IOPAD(0x824, PIN_OUTPUT | MUX_MODE4)    /* gpmc_ad9.ehrpwm2B  */
        >;
     };
};

/ {
    soc {
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&hw_pins>;
    };
};
```

However the debugfs still shows mode 7 for the pin

```
/sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl/44e10800.pinmux-pinctrl-single # cat pins | grep 824
pin 9 (PIN9) 44e10824 00000027 pinctrl-single
```

I don't see in the device tree that this pin get's redefined

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Hello...did you try config-pin yet, e.g. config-pin p9.14 pwm ? This may help in userland when muxing is needed from the command line and this is outside of muxing in .dtbo files or .dts files.

Comment: @DeFunct I'm using busybox instead. So there is no config-pin. Anyway thanks for help, the problem is solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution, I had to put pinctrl properties inside another node.
I guess that's because soc node already has pinctrl properties defined.

```
&am33xx_pinmux {
    hw_pins: hw_pins {
        pinctrl-single,pins = <
             AM33XX_IOPAD(0x824, PIN_OUTPUT | MUX_MODE4)    /* gpmc_ad9.ehrpwm2B  */
        >;
     };
};

/ {
    soc {
        mydriver {
              compatible = "mydriver";

              pinctrl-names = "default";
              pinctrl-0 = <&hw_pins>;
        };
       
    };
};
```